# Field Interaction

Tags: field-theory, interactions

Can someone please explain (if possible) the fundamentals of the (for lack of a better word) physical interaction that governs the behavior between fields?

Comment: Do you know what a differential equation is?

Comment: Vaguely from high school...from memory the equation shows a ratio of change between things hypothetically physical?

Comment: i think this question is a bit too broad. Exactly what counts as 'fundamentals' is very subjective, but according to anybody's definition, there's a lot.

Comment: A differential equation isn't inherently about physics. It shows the direction and rate of change of some continuous quantity, as depending on other continuous quantities. The "equations of motion" for fields, which describe how they change and interact, are differential equations. Quantum fields then have quantum uncertainty on top of this.